# Remove nested Object with specific value

Tags: c#

I have a class `Point`

```
public class Point
{
    public int Value;
    public Point Next;
}
```

and nested objects of this class defined as below:

```
    var p1 = new Point() { Value = 0 };
    var p2 = new Point() { Value = 1 };
    var p3 = new Point() { Value = -1 };
    var p4 = new Point() { Value = -2 };
    var p5 = new Point() { Value = 2 };
    var p6 = new Point() { Value = 3 };

    p1.Next = p2;
    p2.Next = p3;
    p3.Next = p4;
    p4.Next = p5;
    p5.Next = p6;
    RemoveNegative(p1);
```

I'm looking for a way to delete all `Point`s with negative values

Comment: What you're doing here is implementing [a singly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_lists).

Comment: Is there a reason you don't put all of your `Points` into some sort of `Collection` like a `List`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you basically have a linked list (as orhtej2 pointed out), which means you have to traverse your points one by one. I'm assuming you want to remove negative points and reconnect to the point after it? So in your example:

```
P1 -> P2 -> P3 -> P4 -> P5 -> P6
```

would become

```
P1 -> P2 -> P5 -> P6
```

You want to stop at each point, and scan ahead until you find a non-negative point, then set Next to that point. Then repeat the whole process starting at the new point.

```
public void RemoveNegative(Point p) {
    while (p != null) {
        Point nextPoint = p.Next;
        while (nextPoint != null && nextPoint.Value < 0) {
            nextPoint = nextPoint.Next;
        }
        p.Next = nextPoint;
        p = nextPoint;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
public void RemoveNegative(Point data)
{
    if (data != null)
    {
        Point previous = data;
        Point current = data.Next;

        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.Value < 0)
            {
                previous.Next = current.Next;
            }
            else
            {
                previous = current;
            }

            current = previous.Next;
        }
    }
}
```